# Laravel Carbon diff not show 0 years

Tags: php, laravel, date, php-carbon

I use diff() function  between 2 dates using Carbon

```
$fecha1 = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('2017-12-05');
$fecha2 = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('2018-02-09');
$resta = $fecha2->diff($fecha1)->format('%y years, %m months and %d days');
```

Result

**0 years, 2 months and 4 days**

I would like this result

**2 months and 4 days**

Because years is 0
Any solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `diffInYears()`:

```
$format = $fecha2->diffInYears($fecha1) > 0 ? '%y years, %m months and %d days' : '%m months and %d days';
$resta = $fecha2->diff($fecha1)->format($format);
```

Comment: what about 0 months?

Comment: @MateiMihai use `diffInMonths()`.

Comment: What I wanted to point is that the problem is more complex than it seems to be.. if you have 0 days or 0 months then this solution will not cover those situation (e.g. 1 year and 3 days, 1 year and 2 months, 2 months, 3 months and 5 days).. but of course, your solution is ok for the specific case of op.

Answer (score 0):

A more generic solution. It will store separately each type of diff (year, month, day), and only display it if it's different than 0.

```
<?php
$fecha1 = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('2017-12-05');
$fecha2 = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('2018-02-09');
$diff = $fecha2->diff($fecha1);
$diffByType = [
    "years" => $diff->format("%y"),
    "months" => $diff->format("%m"),
    "days" => $diff->format("%d"),
];
$output = [];
foreach ($diffByType as $type => $diff) {
    if ($diff != 0) {
        $output[] = $diff." ".$type;
    }
}
echo implode(", ", $output);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/vSNhL)

Sample outputs:

> For 2017-12-05 and 2018-12-09: 1 years, 4 days
>
> For 2017-12-05 and 2018-02-05: 2 months

Answer (score 0):

You should consider what happens when your difference includes 0 days or months. There are plenty possibilites which you must cover:

```
function getDifference(string $start, string $end): string
{
    $formatted = (new DateTime($end))->diff(new DateTime($start))->format('%y years, %m months, %d days');
    $nonZeros = preg_replace('/(?<!\d)0\s?[a-z]*,\s?/i', '', $formatted);

    $commaPosition = strrpos($nonZeros, ',');

    return $commaPosition ? substr_replace($nonZeros, ' and', $commaPosition, 1) : $nonZeros;
}

var_dump(
    getDifference('2017-12-05', '2018-02-09'),
    getDifference('2017-12-05', '2017-12-09'),
    getDifference('2013-12-05', '2017-12-09'),
    getDifference('2013-12-05', '2017-10-09')
);
```

The result would be

```
string(19) "2 months and 4 days"
string(6) "4 days"
string(18) "4 years and 4 days"
string(29) "3 years, 10 months and 4 days"
```